# update UICollectionview datasource count dynamically

Tags: swift, uikit

I have an array as datasource.
I update middle item of array and refresh middle cell in collection view after that I append new item at end of array, so effectively my datasource size increases but collectionview still knows old datasource (array) count, so on scroll to right collection view does not create dequeue cell to populate newly added items in array.
so how can I update collectionview datasource count?
"func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int " to update DS count

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `insertItems(at:)` call like this.

```
// Update the data source first
modelsArray.append(Model())

// Ask collectionView to sync with latest data
collectionView.insertItems(at: [
    IndexPath(item: modelsArray.count-1, section: 0)
])
```

This will cause the `UICollectionView` to re-query your dataSource implementation to check numberOfItems and add a new cell at the end as you expect.

Comment: insertItems bumps cpu usage to 100 % at high frequency insertion (0.01 sec)

Comment: I don't think you should be inserting a new item every 0.01 seconds. What can do is - keep collecting all new incoming items into a new array called `toBeAddedModels`, insert these in batches of 10s or 100s depending on your use case. Instead of relying on count, you could also throttle this based on time, insert items every X seconds and not sooner than that.

Comment: I am creating audio wave render like iOS voice memo app, where new sample comes at 0.01sec frequency and need to display it on screen at same tim, so I added it at end of collectionview and scroll collectionview to generate motion

Comment: You should probably be using a `UIScrollView` like [SCScrollableWaveformView](https://github.com/rFlex/SCWaveformView/blob/master/Sources/SCScrollableWaveformView.m) OR a low level API like `CALayer` as in [EZAudioPlot](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/blob/master/EZAudio/EZAudioPlot.m) OR custom path/drawing like [AudioVisualizationView](https://github.com/bastienFalcou/SoundWave/blob/master/SoundWave/Classes/AudioVisualizationView.swift) for this many frequent drawing updates to be more efficient.